# Мой бот отвечает с переодичностью

Tags: python, aiogram

Вылезла проблема которая уже как 4 дня, и не только у меня. Суть проблемы: запускаю я бота, отправляю ему /start, он отвечает на него, но на последующие сообщения он отвечает с бешеной задержкой в 2-3 минуты, иногда эта проблема уходит и он отвечает моментально, но лишь до перезапуска. В чём может быть проблема? Я делал полностью чистого бота в одном файле с одним хэндлером, у того тоже идентичная проблема, но никаких ошибок в консоли нет, раньше на 11 виндовс все работало нормально, и первые дни на убунту тоже.
Система Ubuntu 22.04.1, версия aiogramm'а: 2.24
P.S У знакомого на виндовс 10 и у второго знакомого на арче идентичная проблема

Comment: Сложно провести анализ при отсутствии первички собранной автором вопроса :)

Comment: Очень жаль что сложно, я проводил собственный анализ и выяснил что запрос от аиограмма до телеграмма и обратно доходит очень долго, так кажется будто какие-то проблемы на стороне телеграмма

Comment: Что есть долго? что происходит долго? установка соединения? обработка запроса? передача данных? Где данные что именно вы уже проверили и результаты оных проверок? предлагаете погадать о возможной проблеме или соизволите поделится результатами анализа и указать что вы не смогли понять в этих результатах?

Comment: Установка соединения и передача данных происходит долго

Comment: Не может ли быть такой проблемы, что что-то мониторит трафик и мешает передаче данных? Проблема не обширная, а скорей локальная

Comment: Может, запросто, поэтому и нужен анализ на вашей стороне :) у меня с телеграммом никаких проблем последние дни небыло, может быть кэш ДНС например невалидный, или пачка проксей используемая вами - протухла, и еще миллиард и одна проблема, но искать ее нужно начиная с ваших настроек :)

Comment: В таком случае я пошёл искать проблему, если что отпишусь сюда и напишу решение, вдруг кому понадобится

Answer (score 0):

Я прикрутил MiddleWare'ы к боту и поставил его на все команды (кд 3 секунды), и у меня исчезла эта проблема...